# How to get the file pointer to the next line in c++?

Tags: c++, pointers, newline, file-structure

Given below is a part of my whole program:

```
         void filewrite(fstream &f2)
         {
            f2.seekp(0,ios::beg);
            f2.write(customerno,strlen(customerno));
            f2.seekp(24,ios::beg);
            f2.write(customername,strlen(customername));
            f2.seekp(56,ios::beg);
            f2.write(product,strlen(product));
            f2<<endl;
         }
```

here f2 is the file pointer
customerno,customername and product are strings
0,24 and 56 are respective positions for these strings from the beginning

the problem i m facing is, everytime i m trying to write a new record it is over writing the previous one and not going to the next line.

i want each new record to be aligned with 0th, 24th and 56th position.
how should  i do this ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a reason you need each string to be at a specific location? You could just use a whitespace delimited approach.

Comment: yes it is important !

Comment: Can you post part of the code where you're calling this function? Also, why does the spacing matter?

Comment: seekp give the position in the output stream. So, you are overwriting the same positions every time you call this function.

Comment: You are not writing the terminating NUL so you will have problems determining the lengths of the strings when you read them back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are giving yourself a challenging problem if you use that method. You want to use `std::setw()` to do this for you.

Here is a far simpler method to do this:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std; 
void filewrite(ofstream &f, string customerno, string customername, string product)
{
   f << left << setw(24) << customerno << setw(32) << customername << product << endl;
}
```

Comment: hey thank you so much Andrue. but i have another problem. the pointer is still not going to the next line. the cursor goes back to the top left corner i.e, the beginning of the line. :( help me plz

Comment: I tested the code before I posted and it worked. Can you update your question with how you are calling it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, if i am getting your question right, but if you want to make sure to seek inside the current line you can do it like that:

```
void filewrite(fstream &f2)
{
  long pos = f2.tellp();

  f2.seekp(pos + 0);
  f2.write(customerno,strlen(customerno));
  f2.seekp(pos + 24);
  f2.write(customername,strlen(customername));
  f2.seekp(pos + 56);
  f2.write(product,strlen(product));
  f2<<endl;
}
```

This only works as intended though, if you can make sure, that the filestream is at the beginning of the next line when the function filewrite is called.

Otherwise i will be kind of complex to find the correct placement of the cursor in the stream.

Comment: Make sure pos is 0 the first time it is called for this method. Also, note that this code will not compile because the variables are out of scope.

Comment: Andrue, thanks for your feedback. You are right, i added three global variables before the function for this code snippet to compile.